# Add a <hr/> element to each element in a class, getting [Object object] or plain text and not the hr element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to add a horizontal bar after sorting the `<div>` that corresponds to the `.pressRow` class. This is my JavaScript function:

```
function SortPressRecent() {
    var $pressRows = $(".pressRow");
    var OrderedDivs = $pressRows.sort(function (a, b) {
        var da = new Date($(a).data("date"));
        var db = new Date($(b).data("date"));
        return da > db ? -1 : da < db;
    });
    $.each(OrderedDivs, function () {
        $(this)[0].append($('<hr />'));
    });
    $("#PressRows").html(OrderedDivs);
}
```

And this is how a `PressRow` looks:

```
<div id="PressRows">
    <div class="row pressRow" data-date="1/13/2010 8:36:00 PM" data-name="AStringHere">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="anImgHere" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <a class="links" href="someLink">AStringHere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ... More pressRows here ...
</div>
```

If I append `$('<hr />')`, it shows up as `[Object object]`. If I add it as `'hr'`, it shows up as text and not the line I want.

Edit: You have all been correct on your answers.  I have realized I have a different issue in that I need to add it after each the closing `</div>` element of each `pressRow` not inside.  I ended up not using the `$.each` function:

```
    function SortPressRecent() {
        var $pressRows = $(".pressRow");
        var OrderedDivs = $pressRows.sort(function (a, b) {
            var da = new Date($(a).data("date"));
            var db = new Date($(b).data("date"));
            return da > db ? -1 : da < db;
        });

        $("#PressRows").html(OrderedDivs);
        $(".pressRow").after('<hr/>');
    }
```

Comment: That's because you're using the wrong [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append). `$(this)[0]` returns the DOM node (`$(this)[0] === this`) but you really wan't the jQuery object.

Comment: Use: `$(this).append('<hr />')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up vanilla JS and jQuery.

Your code is :

```
$(this)[0].append($('<hr />'));
```

which should be

```
$(this).append($('<hr />'));
```

Comment: Also there is no point to make `'<hr />'` a jQuery object. `append('<hr />')` will do the job. The performance difference is negligible, but still no point in doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` method is a jQuery method and requires a jQuery object like `$(this)`. When you try to access the first item with `$(this)[0]`, you get back a JavaScript object, not a jQuery one, so it doesn't have the `append()` method.

Also you can pass HTML string to the `append()` method, so you can simply pass it `'<hr />'` and no need to make it a jQuery object `$('<hr />')`.

Change this line:

```
$(this)[0].append($('<hr />'));
```

to:

```
$(this).append('<hr />');
```

Note: some browsers added support for an `append()` method on JavaScript nodes, but it is not supported on all browsers, so it is not recommended to be used. If you want to try it, then you must pass it a JavaScript node, not a jQuery object. Change the line above to:

```
$(this)[0].append($('<hr />')[0]);
```